# SQL Oracle: Combining consecutive rows

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

```
    | RecordId | high_speed |   speed  | DateFrom   |  DateTo     |
    ---------------------------------------------------------------
    | 666542   |   60       |   10     | 09/11/2011 |  10/11/2011 |
    | 666986   |   20       |   20     | 11/11/2011 |  11/11/2011 |
    | 666996   |   0        |   0      | 13/11/2011 |  17/11/2011 |
    | 755485   |   0        |   0      | 01/11/2011 |  14/11/2011 |
    | 758545   |   70       |   50     | 15/11/2011 |  26/11/2011 |
    | 796956   |   40       |   40     | 09/11/2011 |  09/11/2011 |
    | 799656   |   25       |   20     | 09/11/2011 | 09/11/2011  |
    | 808845   |   0        |   0      | 15/11/2011 | 15/11/2011  |
    | 823323   |   0        |   0      | 15/11/2011 | 16/11/2011  |
    | 823669   |   0        |   0      | 17/11/2011 | 18/11/2011  |
    | 899555   |   0        |   0      | 18/11/2011 | 19/11/2011  |
    | 990990   |   20       |   10     | 12/11/2011 | 12/11/2011  |
```

Here, I want to construct database view which combines the consecutive rows having speed = 0. In that case, DateFrom will be the DateFrom value from first row & DateTo will be the DateTo value of last row.
Which results into table as follows:

```
| high_speed |    speed  | DateFrom    |    DateTo    |
---------------------------------------------------
|  60        |     10    |  09/11/2011 |  10/11/2011  |
|  20        |     20    |  11/11/2011 |  11/11/2011  |
|  0         |     0     |  13/11/2011 |  14/11/2011  |
|  70        |     50    |  15/11/2011 |  26/11/2011  |
|  40        |     40    |  09/11/2011 |  09/11/2011  |
|  25        |     20    |  09/11/2011 |  09/11/2011  |
|  0         |     0     |  15/11/2011 |  19/11/2011  |
|  20        |     10    |  12/11/2011 |  12/11/2011  |
```

Is there any possible way to get result in database view or function?

**Note** - 
1. Removed devID column. It was very confusing instead of it added another column for understanding of the question.
2. Also additionally, I need to add one "**Period**" column i.e function which is difference of "DateFrom" & "DateTo" column.

Comment: you may use the 'merge function

Comment: Can you please give link for reference or any sample code so that I can build view?

Comment: And what should the dev_id field be?

Comment: is there a reason the 1123 devID isn't included in the result but the 1511 is?

Comment: @pablomatico - devID is any value field.

Comment: @JeremyC. - There is no specific reason. In this we need to fetch coulmn values from first row except "DateTo" from last row when speed = 0 thats it. devID is just random number field.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - It will be better if expected solution for Oracle as I am using Oracle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This query using analytic functions `lag()`, `lead()` and some logic with `case ... when` gives desired output:

```
select high_speed, speed, datefrom, dateto, dateto-datefrom period
  from (
    select recordid, high_speed, speed, datefrom, 
      case when tmp = 2 then lead(dateto) over (order by recordid) 
                        else dateto end dateto, tmp 
      from (
        select test.*, case when speed <> 0 then 1 
                       when lag(speed) over (order by recordid) <> 0 then 2
                       when lead(speed) over (order by recordid) <> 0 then 3 
                       end tmp
          from test )
      where tmp is not null)
   where tmp in (1, 2) order by recordid
```

<sup>[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2af90/2)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for query which is useful to us. Please check http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8c214/1 which fails when there is only one consecutive row with speed = 0. It is showing wrong value for DateTo.

Comment: You need to modify conditions for `case` slightly, please check: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8c214/14). This also changes behavior of query when row(s) with speed 0 are at beginning or at the and of data.

Comment: Ohh.. Great !! Thanks a lot @Ponder Stibbons.  Its now working properly for me.

Comment: What would be the best way to send parameter to inner nested query?

Comment: Is your last question directly connected to original? If no - the correct action is to ask new question in main forum - this way you have better chances for correct answer. And please specify, now I don't catch if you have ORA-00904 like in [this example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7/3275) or if you want to pass something from your client application, etc?
Maybe [something like this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7/3280) is what you're after - but it's just guessing.If you are asking something else - please build full new question.

Comment: Created [new question| http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30958088/sql-oracle-combining-consecutive-rows-with-filter].

Comment: OK.You can add the "Oracle" tag, not only "Oracle11g" to your new question - in this way it will attract more attention.

Answer (score 1):

This is another approach for the same solution. It uses `lag()`, `lead()` and `partition by`

The difference to the previous solution is that this query binds rows by **consecutive periods minding the gaps**, i.e:

*Consider all rows with speed 0.*

- row 1: 01/11 to 14/11
- row 2: 15/11 to 18/11
- row 3: 20/11 to 22/11

**Result:**

- row 1: 01/11 to 18/11 (*merged rows 1 and 2*)
- row 2: 20/11 to 22/11 (row 3 is separated because of the gap 19/11)

**Also note that periods that share the same days like 15/11-15/11 and 13/11-17/11 will break this query.** The sample data provided has periods like this.

```
-- for better understanding, start reading from the most nested query to the outer

-- QUERY 4: Removes duplicates

-- this query removes duplicates, because both border-rows on a multiple-row period will be identical
-- after the query 3

select distinct
    high_speed,
    speed,
    datefrom,
    dateto,
    dateto-datefrom period
from
(

-- QUERY 3: Selects border-rows and builds datefrom and dateto.

-- this query selects all border-rows, which have the datefrom and dateto data that we need
-- to build the bigger period row.
--
-- this query also builds the bigger period datefrom and dateto

select
    high_speed,
    speed,
    CASE WHEN is_previous_a_border = 0 and is_next_a_border = 1 then lag(datefrom) over (partition by speed order by datefrom)
         WHEN is_previous_a_border = 1 and is_next_a_border = 0 then datefrom
         WHEN is_previous_a_border = 1 and is_next_a_border = 1 then datefrom
         ELSE null END datefrom,
    CASE WHEN is_previous_a_border = 0 and is_next_a_border = 1 then dateto
         WHEN is_previous_a_border = 1 and is_next_a_border = 0 then lead(dateto) over (partition by speed order by datefrom)
         WHEN is_previous_a_border = 1 and is_next_a_border = 1 then dateto
         ELSE null END dateto
from (

-- QUERY 2: Create syntax-sugar

-- this query creates some syntax-sugar properties:
--    - "is_previous_a_border": defines if previous row is a border
--    - "is_next_a_border": defines if previous row is a border

select 
    high_speed,
    speed,
    datefrom,
    dateto,
    is_border,
    nvl(lag(is_border) over (partition by speed order by datefrom), 1) as is_previous_a_border,
    nvl(lead(is_border) over (partition by speed order by datefrom), 1) as is_next_a_border
 from (

-- QUERY 1: Create "is_border" property

-- this query creates the "is_border" property, which defines if a row is a border of a bigger multiple-row period
-- we use partition by to group rows and lag/lead to flag rows with consecutive periods
--
-- note that both border-rows of a bigger multiple-row period will have is_border = 1, while all rows in between
-- them, will have is_border = 0.

select
    high_speed,
    speed,
    datefrom,
    dateto,
    case when lead(datefrom) over (partition by speed order by datefrom) between datefrom and dateto + interval '1' day
         and lag(dateto) over (partition by speed order by datefrom) between datefrom - interval '1' day and dateto then 0
    else 1 end is_border
from
    test))
where is_border = 1)
order by
  speed, datefrom;
```

[SQL Fiddle (with altered sample data)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fedef/1)